# PHP: Help with adaptive payments and embedded process

Tags: php, paypal

So currently I am using the PaypalNVP class by Peter Reisinger.  It's pretty awesome doing what it does.

However, now I need to use everything that adaptive payments offers and more **importantly** need to use the embedded process option.

I've downloaded the [PHP SDK](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks), (so no need to tell me about it).

I've got the samples working (these are: Pay, PaymentDetails, Preapproval, etc).  But they all seem to post directly to the sandbox and then just return information.

But the biggest problem is that **there is no payment flow**!

Before you say it, I've got the [Adaptive Payments 
Developer Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf) but it might be a little too much for me.  :(  I'd rather just lean on a class and make it do the bulk of work for me.  :)

This is the back story, my question is I can't find a way to do a simple pay payment flow using adaptive payments using the embedded process.

Can anyone point me into the direction of an updated class (not something circa 2005), or if you have some time, knock up an example!

To be honest, an example would be better.  I learn better looking at other peoples code :)

Edit: I've even seen this, but: [it's of little help really](https://www.x.com/people/Praveen/blog/2010/11/01/switching-over-to-embedded-payments)

Cheers

Comment: After digging through lots of SO posts.  I came across this: http://www.zerogravpro.com/PayPal/Articles/DigitalGoodsExpressCheckout/DigiGoodsEC.html  Will pick through the code and hopefully it helps me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After headbanging for a while, the link I commented with earlier worked for me!

http://www.zerogravpro.com/PayPal/Articles/DigitalGoodsExpressCheckout/DigiGoodsEC.html

Comment: That's for Express Checkout, which is a different product from Adaptive Payments.